# Large city file that needs to be made manifold but is too complex and will always make blender crash

Tags: mesh, remesh, blender-osm

I have a big and complex file, an stl that was imported from blenderOSM (openstreetmap) and it imports meshes found in google maps via an addon.

In my case I imported the Vatican and the whole idea is to get the file to a manifold, 3dprintable state. I need the file to keep most of the detail too.

[image]

The problem is that it has so many non manifold geometry that when trying to use the modifier *Remesh* it will most certainly crash. I have tried simplifying the mesh by merging vertices by distance, but this still doesn't take care of inner geometry in most of the buildings.

[image]

I have even tried using other software such as Maya and trying to remesh and retopo but it still will get my pc to crash.

There is an option in the blenderosm addon that lets you import the buildings from the OSM database, but these ones are nowhere nearly as detailed as the google map ones (photo 4). Google maps has even the trees, bridges, canals and even the cars included.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't really help with this since we have no access to your mesh. Also it's way to big and complex, I doubt it can be solved without manually going through every problematic non-manifold area. Why don't you do it by smaller chunks? I think that is the only alternative.

Comment: Hello @HarryMcKenzie thanks for the reply! I will try to upload the mesh. Indeed it is very complex but I have been able to remesh another file once, it was another city and while it took a lot of time it did work.

Comment: Quad Remesher is a really good remesher addon but its not free.